# Cocos2d portrait mode not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a cocos2d game which is supposed to be in portrait mode. I changed the RootViewController.m to portrait mode, and everything works fine, both on the simulator and on my iPad. However, when I run the game on my iPhone, it defaults back to landscape mode.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a better solution that will work 100%:

Replace all the stuff that was in the RootViewController.m / 
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation Method with following:

> return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interfaceOrientation ) );

And if I ever want to change the orientation during runtime / switching scene:

> [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

Note that Auto Rotation is now on longer supported

Comment: hey alexander, i've tried that, but the upside down mode is also enabled. so how can i ONLY enable the portrait mode?

Comment: are you using Cocos2D 1.x or 2.0 beta?

Answer (score 1):

in GameConfig.h:

use the director for autorotation

```
#if defined(__ARM_NEON__) || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationCCDirector
```

instead of

```
#if defined(__ARM_NEON__) || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

and in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
...
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the RootViewController return false from the method below:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return false; 

   // other code...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In RootViewController.m

```
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
```

change this line to

```
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interfaceOrientation ) );
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did already. It works fine in the Simulator and on my iPad, but for some reason it's not working on my iPhone.

Comment: but now working only for portrait mode , I want  both orientations

Answer (score 0):

in GameConfig.h:

```
For 1st and 2nd generation devices, value is set to kGameAutorotationNone, change it to kGameAutorotationUIViewController.

// ARMv6 (1st and 2nd generation devices): Don't rotate. It is very expensive
#elif __arm__
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone
```