# Cocos2d portrait mode not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a cocos2d game which is supposed to be in portrait mode. I changed the RootViewController.m to portrait mode:

```
 return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interfaceOrientation ) );
```

Everything works fine, both on the simulator and on my iPad. However, when I run the game on my iPhone, it defaults back to landscape mode.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987066/cocos2d-portrait-mode-not-working-on-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ur app delegate.. Put this line:

```
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

after

```
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/30];
[director setDisplayFPS:YES];
```

Comment: hey xuanweng, this line also allows upside down mode. so how can i only allow portrait mode?

Comment: if in your GameConfig.h you set to #define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone?